# What is the correct css for the list of results to show correctly in this situation?

Tags: html, css

What is the correct css for the list of results to show correctly? Here are the steps to view the results:

1) Navigate to http://mypubguide.com/good-pubs/east-region

2) Type "Hull" in the search input on the navigation bar and enter

3) Check: You see a list of results but the styling is incorrect, e.g., the anchor tag is not showing the text correctly and other elements look badly formatted.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: I assume you're responding to the answer by Adrien Leber. Add this to your page/css file: .gsc-webResult { line-height: 21px !important; }. This will fix your problem, but I would advise the answer given because using !important is kind of a 'hack'

Comment: No, that was in response to someone else who left an unhelpful comment

Comment: The issue is now fixed - so I'll clear this down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `line-height` of the `.gcse-container` is `0px`. Set it to `20px` or remove the rule will solve your problem.

Comment: Removing it will work as well as the line-height will be 21px because of the bootstrap styling. Tip: Use F12 (developer tools) to see which styling is being applied to a certain element.

Comment: Thank you @E.Mourits. I update my answer.

Comment: I removed the rule - thanks again